# What do "thou" and "thee" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

I tried to check the meaning of *thou* and *thee* and all I could find is:

> thou = he/she in the past
>
> thee = they in the past

But that doesn't make any sense to me.

This is the context:

> After Anu had created the heaven,
> And the heaven had created the earth,
> And the earth had created the rivers,
> And the rivers had created the canals,
> And the canals had created the morass,
> And the morass had created the worm,
> The worm went before Shamash, weeping,
> His tears flowing before Ea:
> ‘What wilt thou give me for my food,
> What wilt thou give me for my drink?’
> ‘I will give thee the dried fig
> And the apricot.’
> ‘What are these to me? The dried fig
> And the apricot!
> Lift me up, and among the teeth
> And the gums let me dwell! . .
> Because thou hast said this, O worm,
> May Ea smite thee with the might of
> His hand!

What do these thous and thees mean?

I also read that *Shamash* is the god in an ancient civilization, so what does it mean when it states: *The worm went before Shamash*? How could the worm go before this god? Or does it have a hidden meaning?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the grammar and vocabulary of a very old "translation" of the "poetic" [Epic of Gilgamesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh), obviously produced [at least before 1834](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22After+Anu+had+created+the+heavens+so+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), and not relevant to the needs of people learning *normal, current* English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not quite so old as that. Your link is a review of a translation by R.C. Thompson published in 1904; and in fact, OP's version appears to be slightly retouched from of a translation by [Alexander Heidel, p.72](https://oi.uchicago.edu/sites/oi.uchicago.edu/files/uploads/shared/docs/misc_genesis.pdf), 1952.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And now I look closely, part of the retouch is a replacement of *went* with *came* ... but I'm pretty sure of Heidel as the source: it's the only translation I've found which employs 'morass'. I think this is a sloppy transcription on some 3rd- or 4th-party website.

Comment: @StoneyB: oic. Well, it wouldn't really make any difference if it was written yesterday. It's English, Jim, but not as we know it.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea where you got this notion that *thou/thy/thine/thee* have anything to do with the third person singular pronounts, but it is quite wrong.

*Thou* (subjective), *thy/thine* (possessive), and *thee* (objective) are the forms taken by the now-obsolete second-person-singular pronoun. Between about 1500 and 1700 this was replaced by the pronoun *you* (which was originally the objective form of the second-person-plural pronoun *ye*); during that period it came to act primarily (but inconsistently) as a familiar or affectionate form, contrasting with *you* as the formal or respectful form.

Today it survives only in religious or historic contexts, or as here to translate corresponding forms from other languages.

As for *The worm went before Shamash*, you will have to consult the notes in your source, or other scholarly works dealing with the language and literature of the Ancient Near East; keep in mind that this is a translation from a dead language (and a dead culture) which is only imperfectly known today, so this cannot be adddressed on ELL. A translation I consulted renders that line “The worm came weeping before Shamash”—*before*, that is, in the sense of *into the presence of*. The worm appears to be either a personification of the entity causing toothache, or the entity itself.

Comment: Perhaps "went" was meant to be *wept*

Comment: @Jim Could be; but my guess is that whatever morpheme appears in the original acts as both *come* and *go*.

Comment: Actually I just read the thing instead of commenting blindly and *went before Shamash, weeping* makes perfect sense and, I think comes off nearly identical to "came weeping before Shamash" but the former seems more consistent with the style of language in KJB.

Comment: @Jim Well, it's 'went' that seems to have confused OP, leading them to think that 'went before' indicates some sort of precedence.

Comment: Oh, ha ha, didn't even think of that interpretation.